# How do I add a column which is scaled by value of specific level in r?

Tags: r

I have a data set like this (note headings `I`, `J` and `Value`):

```
myData = read.table(text="
I J Value\n
A X 5
A Y 10
A Z 20
B X 80
B Y 120
B Z 40
C X 30
C Y 60
C Z 90", header = TRUE)
```

### Problem:

I would like to add a column (called `RelValue`) to `myData` with a value equal to Value devided by `Value` for each `I` where `J` is `Z`.

The equation for would look something like this: 
`RelValue(I,J) = Value(I,J)/Value(I|J=Z)`

So the added column `RelValue` should end up like this:

```
RelValue
0.25
0.5
1.0
2.0
3.0
1.0
1/3
2/3
1.0
```

**Any ideas on how I could do this?** (coming from java I have unsuccessfully been fighting with loops for hours - but figure this must be easier now I'm in R).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(myData`), grouped by "I", we divide 'Value' by the 'Value' where 'J' is 'Z' (assuming there is only a unique 'Z' for the 'J' column in each 'I' group) and assign (`:=`) it to create a new column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(myData)[, RelValue := round(Value/Value[J=="Z"],2) , by = I]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we use the similar methodology.

```
library(dplyr)
myData %>%
       group_by(I) %>%
       mutate(RelValue = round(Value/Value[J=="Z"], 2))
#       I      J Value RelValue
#  <fctr> <fctr> <int>    <dbl>
#1      A      X     5     0.25
#2      A      Y    10     0.50
#3      A      Z    20     1.00
#4      B      X    80     2.00
#5      B      Y   120     3.00
#6      B      Z    40     1.00
#7      C      X    30     0.33
#8      C      Y    60     0.67
#9      C      Z    90     1.00
```

---

Or using `ave`

```
with(myData, round(Value/ave(Value * (J=="Z"), I, FUN = max),2))
#[1] 0.25 0.50 1.00 2.00 3.00 1.00 0.33 0.67 1.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R method, using `split` and `lapply`:

```
unlist(lapply(split(myData, myData$I), function(i) {
                                       round(i$Value / i[i$J == "Z", "Value"], 2)}))
```

The `split` function partitions the data.frame by I. Then `lapply` loops through each partition and applies the function. Finally, since `lapply` returns a list, we transform it into a vector using `unlist`.